# R Simulation Programming Efficiency

Tags: r, simulation, apply, performance, sapply

I am a relatively new R programmer and have written a script that takes some statistical results and will ultimately compare it to a vector of results in which the target variable has been randomized.  The result vector contains the statistical results of n simulations.  As the number of simulations increases (I would like to run 10,000 simulations at least) the run time is longer than I would like.  I have tried increasing the performance in ways I know to modify the code, but would love the help of others in optimizing it.  The relevant part of the code is below.

```
#CREATE DATA   

require(plyr)

Simulations <- 10001
Variation <- c("Control", "A", "B","C")
Trials <- c(727,724,723,720)
NonResponse <- c(692,669,679,682)
Response <- c(35,55,44,38)
ConfLevel <- .95

#PERFORM INITIAL CALCS  

NonResponse <- Trials-Response
Data <-data.frame(Variation, NonResponse, Response, Trials)
total <- ddply(Data,.(Variation),function(x){data.frame(value = rep(c(0,1),times =   c(x$NonResponse,x$Response)))})
total <- total[sample(1:nrow(total)), ]
colnames(total) <- c("Variation","Response")

#CREATE FUNCTION TO PERFORM SIMULATIONS   

targetshuffle <- function(x) 
{
  shuffle_target <- x[,"Response"] 
  shuffle_target <- data.frame(sample(shuffle_target)) 

  revised <- cbind(x[,"Variation"], shuffle_target) 
  colnames(revised) <- c("Variation","Yes")

  yes_variation <- data.frame(table(revised$Yes,revised$Variation))
  colnames(yes_variation) <- c("Yes","Variation","Shuffled_Response")
  Shuffled_Data <- subset(yes_variation, yes_variation$Yes==1)
  Shuffled_Data <- Shuffled_Data[match(Variation, Shuffled_Data$Variation),]
  yes_variation <- cbind(Data,Shuffled_Data)

  VectorPTest_All <- yes_variation[,c("Variation","NonResponse","Response","Trials","Shuffled_Response")]
  Control_Only <- yes_variation[yes_variation$Variation=="Control",]
  VectorPTest_Chall <- subset(yes_variation,!(Variation=="Control"))
  VectorPTest_Chall <- VectorPTest_Chall[,c("Variation","NonResponse","Response","Trials","Shuffled_Response")] 

  ControlResponse <- Control_Only$Response
  ControlResponseRevised <- Control_Only$Shuffled_Response
  ControlTotal <- Control_Only$Trials
  VariationCount <- length(VectorPTest_Chall$Variation)          

  VP <- data.frame(c(VectorPTest_Chall,rep(ControlResponse),rep(ControlResponseRevised),rep(ControlTotal)))

  names(VP) <- c("Variation","NonResponse","Response", "Trials", "ResponseShuffled", "ControlReponse", 
             "ControlResponseShuffled","ControlTotal")

  VP1 <<- data.frame(VP[,c(5,7,4,8)]) 
  VP2 <<- data.frame(VP[,c(3,6,4,8)]) 

  ptest <- apply(VP1, 1, function(column) prop.test(x=c(column[1], column[2]), 
                                               n=c(column[3], column[4]),  alternative="two.sided", 
                                               conf.level=ConfLevel,  correct=FALSE)$p.value)

  min_p_value <- min(ptest)

  return(min_p_value)
}

#CALL FUNCTION   

sim_result <- do.call(rbind, rlply(Simulations, targetshuffle(total)))
```

Comment: I suggest you try [profiling your code](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html#profiling). Figure out exactly what's taking the most time. Avoid reassigning large objects if possible. Or maybe all the time is spent in `prop.test` and the rest doesn't matter. But in general please-fix-this-code-for-me "questions" aren't really on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Offhand, one thing to look at is creating all the data frames. Each time you do that you're copying all the data in the constituent object. If the dimensions are predictable you might consider creating empty matrices at the beginning of the function and populating them as you go.